# Inserting integral symbol in table or matrix

Tags: tables, lyx

I want to include an integral symbol with a "C" subscript in a table or matrix, but the "C" ends up in the wrong place. I'm a basic LyX user with minimal/zero LaTeX coding ability. I can copy/paste text into that red "insert TeX code" thing, and that's about it. Any suggestions please?[image]

Comment: `$\displaystyle\int_C$`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - using that in both matrix and table cells the "C" is in the wrong place, ie not directly under the integral sign.

Comment: Then `$\displaystyle\int\limits_C$`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Wow! That works. I've been poodling around with this all day. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things at work here.  First, the smaller integral sign is displayed in `$` delimited inline text-style, so the `\displaystyle` is needed to obtain the larger sign.

Secondly, the default for the CM font is to have the integral limit to the right, rather than below, the integral.  One can overcome that with `\limits`, as shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\int_C\quad \int\limits_C
\]
$\displaystyle\int_C\quad \int\limits_C$
\end{document}
```

[image]